# Custom Github Shields

Tags: github, automation, shields.io

How do you make custom GitHub shields that track status on your repository?

I am using shields.io and have figured out how to use a Jenkins plugin to expose the build status and create a shield, but wondering how others automate status for code coverage, documentation coverage, linting, unit tests, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Code coverage, linting, etc. are provided by various services that you have to sign up with. For example, [coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io) provides test coverage. Another popular service that provides many different types of code analysis and coverage tools is [Code Climate](https://codeclimate.com). Most of those sites provide badges you can add to your GitHub repo, usually in the README.

For example, a repo I maintain has accounts with Travis, Gemnasium, and Code Climate, and I have badges for those services on my README: https://github.com/monfresh/ohana-sms

Comment: The question is about how those people did to give that service